# How to make an apDiv show up in same spot on all browsers

Tags: php, html, flash

I'm pretty new to the whole webmaster stuff and am just trying to format a slideshow on my homepage to be in a certain area with an [apDiv](http://www.adobepress.com/articles/article.asp?p=1332864), but as soon as I use another browser it's in a different location. Is there a way to make them appear in the same spot for all browsers?

Here's a screen shot:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you are using CSS with absolute positioning, you should be able to control positioning in any modern browser.

You might have a look at this tutorial on positioning: http://tutorialzine.com/2010/06/microtut-how-css-position-works/

Comment: thanks ill check that out now and see if i can do what i was trying to achieve